# Inserting an array with less elements as new column to an existing DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Using the `df.insert() function` I want to add to an existing `DataFrame` a new column which I have in terms of an array (without any indexing). I know that my array has less entries than the DataFrame rows. This is intended. I want NaN values in the end of the new column to match the size of the DataFrame. However, I don't know how to accomplish this since I get the

```
ValueError: Length of values (999) does not match length of index (1000)
```

Any ideas how to pad my array with one NaN (or NaT) value to make it match?

**Edit:** Here the code which generates the problems with @Tranbi's answer:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
times=np.random.randint(365*24*60,size=1000)
dates=datetime(2022,1,1)+timedelta(minutes=1)*times
data=pd.DataFrame({'date':np.sort(dates)})
data.set_index('date',inplace=True)
diff=(data.index[1:]-data.index[:-1]).array
pd.Series(diff).reindex(data.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reindex` with your df index as argument:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "A": [420, 380, 390],
  "B": [50, 40, 45]
}

C = [1, 2]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.insert(2, "C", pd.Series(C).reindex(df.index))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A   B    C
0  420  50  1.0
1  380  40  2.0
2  390  45  NaN
```

Edit: regarding your edit, the confusion comes from the fact that you're setting your date as index. Why don't you work with Series? It would be less confusing:

```
times=np.random.randint(365*24*60,size=1000)
dates=pd.Series(np.sort(datetime(2022,1,1)+timedelta(minutes=1)*times))
pd.Series(dates[1:].values - dates[:-1].values).reindex(dates.index)
```

Edit2: using `diff` as starting point, we reindex with `range(len(data))` in order to get the right number of rows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

times=np.random.randint(365*24*60,size=1000)
dates=datetime(2022,1,1)+timedelta(minutes=1)*times
data=pd.DataFrame({'date':np.sort(dates)})
data.set_index('date',inplace=True)

diff = (data.index[1:]-data.index[:-1]).array

new_col = pd.Series(diff).reindex(range(len(data)))
data.insert(0, "new", new_col.values)
```

Comment: Looks very good at the first sight. But somehow when I reindex my `pd.Series(C)` I obtain a series with `NaT` values at every place (not only the last one). My array `C` is a `TimedeltaArray`. The `pd.Series(C)` however looks correct.

Comment: I tried with a TimedeltaArray and it works as expected (missing values are NaT)... would you mind sharing a sample data causing the problem?

Comment: In my example I skipped a lot of unnecessary code in order to don't overload the example. In my application however the dates come naturally as index and I need to be able to deal with that situation.

Comment: Fair enough. then do `ds = pd.Series(data.index)` and `pd.Series(ds[1:].values - ds[:-1].values).reindex(ds.index)`

Comment: And how do I insert the diffs as new column of DataFrame `data` then?

Comment: Just insert the values (not the series since indexes differ). `new_col = pd.Series(ds[1:].values - ds[:-1].values).reindex(ds.index)` then `data.insert(0, "new", new_col.values)`

Comment: Thanks, that works. Thus, you have solved the problem for my application. However, just for curiosity, I wonder if there is a way how to achieve the same result by working with the array `diff=(data.index[1:]-data.index[:-1]).array`. By the way: Could you edit the answer you gave in the comments to the actual answer? I want to accept it but for that purpose I think the answer should be visible in the answer itself.

Comment: I added a second edit